# Get-ChildItem : The network path was not found

Tags: powershell

While running my power shell script to get largest files from multiple servers, am facing this error. Could some one help me to resolve this error.

**Script:**

```
$computers = get-content -Path "D:\Automation_space_check\Servers.txt."
foreach($_ in (Get-WmiObject win32_volume -ComputerName $computer)){
if($_.drivetype -eq 3 -and $_.driveletter -ne $null){
Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\$($_.driveletter.replace(':','$'))" -force -recurse -ErrorAction silentlycontinue | select Name,DirectoryName,@{Name="size";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.length/1mb)}} |
 Sort Size -descending | select -first 10}}
```

**Error:**

> Get-ChildItem : The network path was not found At
> D:\Automation_space_check\Untitled3.ps1:18 char:1
> + Get-ChildItem "\$computer$($_.driveletter.replace(':','$'))" -force ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

**Servers.txt**

```
Computer1
computer2
computer3
computer4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$computers = get-content -Path "D:\Automation_space_check\Servers.txt."
foreach($computer in  $computers) {
  foreach($drive in (Get-WmiObject win32_volume -ComputerName $computer)) {
    if($drive.drivetype -eq 3 -and $drive.driveletter -ne $null){
        Get-ChildItem "\\$computer\$($_.driveletter.replace(':','$'))" -force -recurse -ErrorAction silentlycontinue | select Name,DirectoryName,@{Name="size";Expression={"{0:N1}" -f($_.length/1mb)}} |
        Sort Size -descending | select -first 10
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: getting another error now like:   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\Automation_space_check\Untitled3.ps1:19 char:39
+ ... Get-ChildItem "\\$computers\$($_.driveletter.replace(':','$'))" -forc ...
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: `$computers` is a collection. The path if you have followed the example use `\\$computer`.
I would suggest that you set breakpoint on your code and inspect the values of the various variables to find the one which is null. You probably have to include some `if` statement or even `try {} catch {}` blocks to handle some errors.